# The global (weak) dimension of formal power series rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, power-series

Given a commutative ring $R$, what are relations between  w.gldim$(R)$ and w.gldim$(R[[x]])$ (gldim$(R)$ and gldim$(R[[x]])$)?

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: I like the question since $R$ is rather general (ok, the commutivity condition could be dropped, but that wouldn't essentially effect the results stated in my answer). In particular I would be interested in knowing the global dimension if $R$ is not Noetherian. 

Comment: @FernandoMuro It's still an open problem as of end of 2023.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R$ be commutative.

1. If $R$ is Noetherian, then $\text{gl.dim}(R[[X]]) = 1 + \text{gl.dim}(R)$.
2. If $R[[X]]$ is coherent, then $\text{w-gl.dim}(R[[X]]) = 1 + \text{w-gl.dim}(R)$.

Now let $R$ be Noetherian. Hence $R[[X]]$ is Noetherian and since global and weak-global dimension agree for Noetherian rings, we obtain:
$$\text{gl.dim}(R[[X]]) = 1 + \text{gl.dim}(R) = \text{w-gl.dim}(R[[X]]).$$

The first result is Theorem 1.12 of the paper

[Auslander, Buchsbaum: Homological dimension in Noetherian rings, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 88(1958),194-206](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1958-088-01/S0002-9947-1958-0096720-1/S0002-9947-1958-0096720-1.pdf)

and the second is Lemma 1 of

[Jondrup, Small: Power Series over coherent rings, Math. Scand. 35(1974), 21-24](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/en/dms/toc/?PPN=PPN35397434X_0035).

Comment: Is point 1 true for not commutative and/or not noetherian ring R? Like in case of polynomial ring.

Comment: @jsfdlkdj: I don't know. At least the proof of Auslander, Buchsbaum doesn't work in general (since it use localization). 